# Is web Scraping/Automation against site terms of use Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, work, fatwa, software

**Al salam Alykom**
I know this question had been asked before but it doesn't appear which answer is the correct one.

- **Is scraping web sites' data is haram?** websites usually doesn't agree that bots crawl it?
  I am scraping data from public available web pages,it can be copied manually but instead a bot saves the time & the effort.
- **Is web automation haram?** for example bot login to my account ,post some data on my account.
  usually it is against website terms of use too,But is it fair!?

I found arabic fatwa on [Islamweb](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/379102/) which says that web scraping is allowed because the data are publicaly available,the fatwa did not mention anything about terms of use ,so maybe the chekh doesn't know the whole story?or i am just too incredulous .

sorry for any language mistake.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, web scraping is breaking the Terms of service of most services. This is i would think a subset of breaking the law. Visit the link to see what the ruling is for breaking the law

https://www.islamicboard.com/advice-amp-support/15902-breaking-law-haram.html#post202462

Comment: I heard that web scraping of public content in australia is allowed<i know copy right protected data can't be used for harming the owners>[more details](https://www.quora.com/Is-web-data-scraping-legal-in-Australia-The-data-I-want-to-be-scraped-from-the-website-wont-be-published-anywhere-it-will-be-solely-used-for-internal-research-for-my-company)

Answer (score 0):

It would be good to ensure that you're scraping any contents which are publicly available. In terms of web automation being haram? This is down to how you use it. Web automation can involve the creation of malicious bots which could perhaps cause a disruption to a service or perhaps attempt exploitation. In that case, unless you have written consent from the website owners such as you are engaging in a bug bounty.

A bug bounty is a program in which you identify vulnerabilities for a website system and you have been given permission to attempt exploiting a list of vulnerabilities, this is what we call a scope. A scope is a list of rules you must legally abide by and if you make any mistakes you must be sure to report them and to be honest and considerate about any sensitive information you may find. You need to consider that when you are finding the faults in a system with given permission, it is an amanah that you must protect the knowledge of these faults and never to leak these faults to anybody else to prevent third parties from causing harm.

Otherwise, if you have not been given any permission. It is not recommended to be doing this as you're breaking the law and of course this is not something a Muslim should be doing knowingly.

On the other hand, web automation can be used for legitimate reasons such as logging into a personal account of your own and automating some tasks. I believe it is down to your use case, your intentions and whether you have been given permission by the owners of the service to conduct the activity. Alternatively, if the account is yours then this is your personal data.

May Allah continue to grant you knowledge in web based technologies and grant you halal rizq from this line of work. Ameen

Answer (score 0):

In Islamic law, the concept of Halal (permissible) and Haram (forbidden) extends to many aspects of life, including business transactions and ethical behavior. Web scraping in itself is a technical action and doesn't have an intrinsic Halal or Haram status; however, the ethical and legal considerations surrounding it could make it either Halal or Haram depending on the specific circumstances.

Respect for Property: In Islam, respecting others' property and rights is a fundamental principle. If a website's terms of service explicitly state that scraping is not allowed, then doing so could be considered a form of stealing or deception, which is Haram in Islam.

Trust and Honesty: Islam places a strong emphasis on being honest and fulfilling trusts. If you agree to a website's terms of service and then violate them, this could be seen as dishonest.

No Harm Principle: Islamic business ethics operate under the principle of causing no harm. If your scraping activities harm the business in some way, it may be considered Haram.

Legal Adherence: Islam encourages following the laws of the land you are in, as long as those laws do not force you to do something that is Haram. If web scraping is illegal or against the terms of service in your jurisdiction, it would also likely be considered Haram.

If you're considering web scraping and want to ensure that it's Halal, you might consult with a qualified Islamic scholar who can provide a perspective based on Islamic law and ethics.